# ImageView "fitXY" scaleType not working on phone

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout, imageview

I am creating an Android application for an RGBCCT LED strip controller. This application is basically a control panel that lets the user specify the colour of the RGB portion of the strip, as well as the colour temperature of the CCT portion. The problem here lies in the slider for selecting the hue of the RGB part. What I want it to be is a seekbar in the default Android style, except the background is a rainbow to reflect the hue spectrum in HSV colours. The problem is that I am unable to get the rainbow image to stretch along the length of the seekbar, such that it starts at red, runs through the entire spectrum, and ends at red. However, the scaling of the image causes it to tile, rather than stretch along the length.

Initially, I tried to create a seekbar style (progress drawable) that does the stretching by itself, but I was unsuccessful. I tried using [bitmaps and scale drawables](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource). As such, I resorted to visualizing the rainbow with an ImageView widget under the seekbar by using a FrameLayout. The ImageView uses the "fitXY" scale type. This seemed like a success, as the preview showed what I had in mind. However, on my phone, the rainbow does not stretch as intended at all, as it does the tiling exactly as it did in the seekbar progress drawable. What am I doing wrong? Could it be related to the way the layout_width parameters are handled?

Here is the XML code of the front page of the application. I collapsed the textview widgets as they are not of interest, at least I think, as they take up loads of lines. The actual seekbar implementation is at the bottom.

```xml
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideInset"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <nl.madmijk.rgbwwcontrolepaneel.ConnectionView
                android:id="@+id/connection_indicator"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_regular" />

            <!-- Top half of the sliders for the CCT portion -->
            <LinearLayout ...> 

            <Space
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_regular" />

            <!-- Bottom half of the sliders for the RGB portion -->
            <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="8dp"
                tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="8dp">

                <ImageView
                    android:id="@+id/RGB_accent"
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_accent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    app:srcCompat="?attr/colorAccent" />

                <Space
                    android:layout_width="@dimen/spacing_regular"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView .../>

                        <TextView .../>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/RGB_bar_intensity"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/seekbar_height"
                        android:max="255"
                        android:progress="0" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_regular" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView .../>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <SeekBar
                        android:id="@+id/RGB_bar_sat"
                        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.SeekBar"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/seekbar_height"
                        android:max="255"
                        android:progress="0" />

                    <Space
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="@dimen/spacing_regular" />

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal">

                        <TextView .../>

                    </LinearLayout>

                    <!-- Here is the portion of interest -->
                    <FrameLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="match_parent">

                            <ImageView
                                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                                android:layout_width="0dp"
                                android:layout_height="@dimen/huebar_thickness"
                                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                                android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
                                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                                android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
                                android:adjustViewBounds="false"
                                android:scaleType="fitXY"
                                android:src="@drawable/hue"
                                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

                        <SeekBar
                            android:id="@+id/RGB_bar_hue"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="@dimen/seekbar_height"
                            android:max="255"
                            android:progress="0"
                            android:progressDrawable="@drawable/hue_seekbar_progress" />

                    </FrameLayout>
                </LinearLayout>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Below are the preview of the layout in Android Studio and the resulting layout on my phone, respectively. 
[Expectations vs reality](http://i.madmijk.nl/1567167637.png) (I cannot embed images yet...)

Just as a test to make sure it is actually a stretching issue, I hard-coded the width of the image, and sure enough, it won't squeeze the image on my phone. [Test preview](https://i.madmijk.nl/1567167357.png), [Test result](https://i.madmijk.nl/1567167365.png).